# Connection to service via CLI not working

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I recently tried to connect to one of our cloud spaces on Swisscom Application cloud using the CLI.

`cf login` worked fine and also `cf push` works as expected.

But if I try to open a ssh tunnel to the mongo db (service) I get an error.

**Creating tunnel ...**

**FAILED**

**Unable to parse domain**

The command I tried:

```
cf service-connector 13000 XXX:YYY
```

where XXX is the host which I took from the service key and YYY the port which I took from there too.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you stumbled on an old issue with the service-connector plugin. Due to a change in the cf-cli the plugin is unable to find the correct endpoint to connect to.

Please ensure you're using the latest cf-cli and service-connector plugin version.
Swisscom service-connector plugin version should be 1.0.8.
You can get it from this site:
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector/

I recommend using cf ssh when ever possible:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html
It requires a service binding to the app you're connecting to.